# Chromium 70 doesn't respect XFCE Window Manager border

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, themes, xfce, chromium

After upgrading from `69.0.3497.81` to `70.0.3538.67` using `sudo apt upgrade`. Using the `--app-id={appId}` flag to open a page as a standalone app, Chromium adds it's own window border with the three dots menu based on my selected GTK theme (Adwaita) and different from my selected Window Manager border (Numix)

[image: Chrome Store using default Adwaita and Numix wm border]

This doesn't happen when using the `--app={url}` flag

How can i force Chromium to respect my Window Manager border?

Comment: I thinks it's related to [this bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=896584) on Chromium.

Comment: Another [related bug](https://crbug.com/896146).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Cause

> This is largely a result of ramping up the security UI for PWA windows
>   so that permission icons (like geolocation) and the site's origin can
>   be shown to the user in a non-spoofable way. Essentially the title bar
>   has taken up the security UI role of the location bar and app menu.

Since Chrome/Chromium 70, Progressive Web Apps (PWA) use Client Side Decorations (CSD) for their window borders. This clashes with the window border defined by your window manager (xfwm in my case) because it gets the colors from the GTK theme instead of the WM theme.

## Answer

To solve the problem Chrome has to:

> Finding a cross platform solution for satisfying our security UI requirements without a title bar

But at the moment this won't be fixed.

> Yeah, it might be reasonable to have some separate configuration to
>   customize the look of these apps once installed. However, this is
>   currently outside of our means (we do not have a lot of resources to
>   dedicate to Linux, and other platforms are much more in the camp of
>   giving developers full control over the look and feel of their
>   windows).

### Workaround

Manually create your own shortcuts to launch PWA in a separated window that uses your window manager border, i.e:

`chromium-browser --app=https://web.whatsapp.com`

Source: [Comments #11, #14 and #32 - Chromium bug tracker](https://crbug.com/896584)

Answer (score 1):

Until version `75.0.3770.142` there is a flag which you can disable to get the native title bar for PWAs. It's `#enable-desktop-pwas`

You can disable it in chrome://flags.

Since `76.0.3809.87` version, this flag disappear. I suppose that is a error becuase there are other flags like `#enable-desktop-pwas-link-capturing` that require the first one, but I'm not entirely sure. I'm in the version `75.0.3770.142` waiting for new versions that fix it.